# Minimum Phone numbers digits Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, woocommerce, phone-number

I want the user to enter a minimum of 7 numbers for their phone number in the Woocommerce checkout. The function below works but it includes spaces, so if user enter 6 numbers with 1 space it counts it as 7. How Can I change the function so that it only counts numbers not spaces so that the user has to enter a minimum of 7 numbers.

```
// validation for Billing Phone checkout field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9 \-]{7}/i', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Phone Number must be <strong>minimum 7 numbers</strong>.' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.

```
$is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9\D]{7}/i', $_POST['billing_phone']);
```

Comment: This will still Count a Space as one of the seven characters.

Answer (score 0):

Change `preg_match` line with this line:

```
$is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9\-]{7}/i', $_POST['billing_phone']);
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately it does not work, if i add 7 numbers with a space in between the error notification appears. It needs to allow 7 number if their is a space in between as it should be 7 minimum even with spaces.

Comment: try doing this to the evaluated string first $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$_POST['billing_phone']); then evaluate $str with the preg_match above. That will remove all white space from the field before you validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex. It only Count the digits:

```
^(?:\D*?\d\D*?){7}$
```

It starts from start of string, then creates a non capturing Group, that matches
optional any number of non digit, digit and optional any number of non digit. It will require exactly 7 of that.

This means, it only Counts the digits and ignore non digits in the Count.

Examples of match:

```
1234567
1 23 45 67
123-4567
```

Example of non-match:

```
123 456
12-34-56-78
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to validate the phone number is:

1. Make sure the $_POST key exists (avoid PHP notice errors)
2. Strip out all non-numbers, and count those only

```php
// validation for Billing Phone checkout field
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
        $phone = strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_POST['billing_phone']));
        if ($phone < 10) {
            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Billing Phone</strong> must be at least 10 digits long.' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```